# Interweave an array's values in place using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

let's say I have an array of numbers => [1,2,3,4,5,6]

and I want to interweave them => [1,4,2,5,3,6]

I can do that with the following code

```js
const nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const results = [];
nums.slice(0, nums.length / 2).forEach((num, index) => results.push(num, nums.slice(nums.length / 2, nums.length)[index]))
console.log(results);
```

to be a better programmer overall, I'd like to know how to modify the array in place as if it were a linked list and without having to create any additional space complexity by having an additional array.

I've written out the logic, but I can't seem to find a pattern to create a function off of.

```
// [0] do nothing

// [1]
currentIndex = 1;
temp = nums[3];
nums[3] = nums[currentIndex];
nums[currentIndex] = temp;
// 1[2]3[4]56 => 1[4]3[2]56

// [2]
currentIndex = 2;
temp = nums[3];
nums[3] = nums[currentIndex];
nums[currentIndex] = temp;
// 14[3][2]56 => 14[2][3]56 

// [3]
currentIndex = 3;
temp = nums[4];
nums[4] = nums[currentIndex];
nums[currentIndex] = temp;
// 142[3][5]6 => 142[5][3]6

// while (currentIndex < nums.length / 2) {...}
```

am I overthinking this?

Comment: [Related on CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/332)

Comment: could you use something like `nums[nums.length - currentIndex]` ? Maybe that doesn't give you the right results

Comment: Note that the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function works on the existing array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function works on the existing array, so you can systematically use that. I've added comments to make it clear what's happening at each step in the loop.

Of course, this will only work with arrays with an even number of elements. I'll leave it to you to make it more generic.

```js
var start = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var half = start.length / 2;
var x = 1;
for (let i = half; i < start.length; i++) {
  let a = start[i]; 
  // remove the existing element
  start.splice(i, 1); 
  // insert it at the right place
  start.splice(x, 0, a); 
  // increment the index of where to insert the next element by two
  x += 2;
}
console.log(start);
```